# Weird issue with PHP and JS scripts, fails the first time until I refresh the page

Tags: javascript, php

I have a PHP page which displays a picture :

```
echo "<p> <img id=\"myPic\" src=\"myPic.png\" > </p>";
```

Later in the code, i'm placing small icons around that picture, using JS :

```
echo "<script>
  var picTop = document.getElementById(\"myPic\").offsetTop ;
  var picLeft= document.getElementById(\"myPic\").offsetLeft ;

  document.getElementById(\"" . $iconId. "\").style.top = picTop + " . $iconPosition[$i][0] . " + \"px\"; 
  document.getElementById(\"" . $iconId. "\").style.left = picLeft + " . $iconPosition[$i][1] . " + \"px\"; 
</script>";
```

I uploaded the page on a server, and other users told me that the icons were overlapping the main picture. However this only happens once, and it is fixed when they reload the page. I've witnessed that too, and i could reproduce the issue by using another browser, again solved by refreshing.

I have no idea what's wrong. Perhaps the main picture takes too long to load, and the JS script has already been performed, so the icons are badly positioned - but it is later fixed because the picture is in the temporary files, or something.

I tried to delay the JS script with a setTimeout, but still didn't fix the problem

```
echo "<script> 
  var picTop = document.getElementById(\"myPic\").offsetTop ;
  var picLeft= document.getElementById(\"myPic\").offsetLeft ;

  setTimeout ( function() {  
  document.getElementById(\"" . $iconId. "\").style.top = picTop + " . $iconPosition[$i][0] . " + \"px\"; 
  document.getElementById(\"" . $iconId. "\").style.left = picLeft + " . $iconPosition[$i][1] . " + \"px\";
}, 500) ; 
</script>";
```

or maybe i could try with more milliseconds... i can't make a proper diagnosis due to the difficulty to reproduce the issue

Thanks for your help !

Comment: load the icons, invisible, then show once moved. or just do it all server side

Comment: What is `$iconId` ? and when are you setting it?

Comment: try wrap your script with this: `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { ... code ... });` or jquery `$(document).ready(function() { .. code ..});`

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<script>
    document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var picTop = document.getElementById(\"myPic\").offsetTop ;
        var picLeft= document.getElementById(\"myPic\").offsetLeft ;

        document.getElementById(\"" . $iconId. "\").style.top = picTop + " . $iconPosition[$i][0] . " + \"px\"; 
        document.getElementById(\"" . $iconId. "\").style.left = picLeft + " . $iconPosition[$i][1] . " + \"px\"; 
    }, false );
</script>";
```